# Encrypt data before send it to the database

Tags: encryption

I was given a task to encrypt data before sending it to the database.

I have a React component in which the user is asked to enter a code. This code is common to all those who try to enter and is not a personal password. It is being stored in the backend, written in Python using Flask. However, I was given a task to encrypt the data in the front-end, send it encrypted to the backend, decrypt the data there, and check if it's valid.

To be honest, I never learned cybersecurity (not sure if it's related), but I thought of creating a hash function that will encrypt and decrypt the data. I also read that there are some libraries in React that can perform encryption or I can implement an algorithm like AES or RSA.

Can someone please guide me and point me to a method that can do the job and is not hard to understand, so I can implement it?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Lin! Welcome. This is a bit unstructured, and thus a bit hard to understand. Could you try to improve it by adding empty lines between independent statements? Generally, adding more punctuation might also help! Thank you.

Comment: hi i edited the question hope its more readable now

Comment: @Lin: please consider "upvoting" and "accepting"  Marcus Müller's excellent reply.  Important points: 1) hashing <> encryption. 2) If your front end uses https/TLS to communicate with the server (as it SHOULD!) ... then you're ALREADY encrypting the data.  Relying on TLS is the "ideal" solution in this case - for many different reasons.

Comment: I can’t upvote his answer

Answer (score 1):

> However, I was given a task to encrypt the data in the front-end, send it encrypted to the backend, decrypt the data there, and check if it's valid.

Tell your operations people to use TLS (i.e., HTTPS instead of just HTTP). Then you're done :) That literally encrypts the data at the frontend and decrypts it at the server.

However, guessing *why* you were told to do this:

This requirement sounds like someone has misunderstood password hashing. Tell whoever formulated that they need to sit down with you and explain what the actual benefit of that is.

Yes, you need encryption, but that's done by the transport, not the application. Yes, you should hash passwords, but you only store the (salted) hash in the database – you do **not** do the hashing in the frontend. That removes all benefits of hashed password storage.

> but I thought of creating a hash function that will encrypt and decrypt the data

Um, that's not a hash function. A hash is irreversible.

Comment: So using TLS will achieve the wanted result with out actually adding.
anything to the existing code?
The one who gave me the task should be an experienced software developer so I don’t know why to give me that task if using TLS will be the best solution
If they do insist on implementing something should I implement an algorithm or use a library?
Sorry for being ignorant but I really am pretty lost in this

Comment: that's why I said you need to sit down with them. I gave you all the answers to the questions you're asking in your comment here in my answer already!